# На что влияет MIME-тип при выдаче файла через PHP

Tags: php

Собственно код

```
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file_name . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', filemtime($file_path)));

readfile($filePath);
```

Параметр `Content-Type` отвечает за тип отдаваемого файла.

**Вопрос:** что изменится если файл будет `audio/wave`, а я напишу `audio/wav` или `audio/mpeg`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Он отвечает за корректную реакцию на стороне клиента. Например, возьмите файрфокс, откройте Options->Applications. Там прописаны действия, которые браузер должен совершать, принимая данный Content-Type. Соответственно, если у вас зарегистрировано одно действие для audio/wave и другое для audio/mpeg - получите соответствующую реакцию. На незарегистрированные типы будет действие по умолчанию.

[image]

Указание типов для inline-элементов типа картинок, например, помогает правильно отрендерить и показать их. В принципе ничего суперфатального не случится, если вы укажете gif вместо png, но лучше так не делать.

А вообще это вопрос уровня "зачем соблюдать стандарты" и "зачем вести себя корректно" :-) Очевидно, чтобы всем было всё понятно, хорошо, удобно и комфортно.